# How to perform a security authentication check in a Rails server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, webserver

I would like to use a web server based on Rails. 
But I have no idea about how to check a user's identification.

For example, a user named Guest could only perform actions like GET and UPDATE on certain tables, while another user named Admin could perform all possible actions such as POST.

I am new to this area, but I heard there are some technicals like SQL injection could threaten the security of the web server.

So, could you tell me how to check the authentication and how to encrypt password entered by the user?

Comment: you could try ACL gems like devise and declarative_authentication

Comment: Devise is not actually an ACL, it's plain authentication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you seem to be wanting is authentication and authorization.

For authentication:
https://github.com/plataformatec/devise
https://github.com/vpereira/authlogic
https://github.com/thoughtbot/clearance

For authorization:
https://github.com/be9/acl9
https://github.com/ryanb/cancan

Answer (score 0):

This is strictly speaking out of my personal experience. I have tried all of the suggested authentication and authorization gems mentioned above, but I always came to the conclusion that its not more or less work to just write it yourself, especially when your requirements a very simple. Consider this:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :authentication

  def authentication
    redirect_to '/authentication_form' unless session[:logged_in]
  end

  def authentication_form
    ... render the form
  end

  def login
    if params[:username] == 'adam' && params[:password] == 'eva'
      session[:logged_in] = true
      redirect_to '/restricted_area'
    else
      render :action => 'authentication_form'
    end
  end
end

class RestrictedController < ApplicationController
  def index
    ... this action is now restricted
  end
end
```

This is not complete, of course but it demonstrates how easy authentication can be with rails. Instead of checking users and passwords through controller code, you could query the database like this:

```
if User.find_by_name_and_password(params[:username], params[:password])
  session[:logged_in] = true
...
```

For authorization you would have to save the users identity within the session hash which allows you to restrict access from within every action (provided the controller is a derived from ApplicationController)

I hope, this helps.

Comment: Hi mosch, it's quite straightforward to have code like this. But I am wonder if it's safe, do we need some more extra work when checking the credential? I think I'd better to check out a standard one.

Comment: I would suggest the practice to not store the plain password within the database. For example `Digest::SHA1.hexdigest(password)` does the job nicely. In addition, I do not recommend against using standard auth solutions. I suppose it greatly depends on your scenario. If you decide to go with a auth gem, you should have a look at devise, which even delivers actions and views.